# Replaced power unit and computer won't show screen

Tags: windows, motherboard, bios, power-supply

I just placed in a brand new PSU and it's a 650W and more then what the system needs. The fans turn on but I don't get anything on the monitor. Ideas?

No beeps. I can't tell if hard drive is running the CPU fan is running at full speed.

EDIT:
Could the motherboard have gone bad? It used to work. Could it be possible to flash the BIOS or something?

**UPDATE:**

SYSTEM
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01466472

New power supply:
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817339012

Comment: You're sure you plugged everything in?  Does the video card need auxillary power?

Comment: "No beeps" would lead me to believe it is not POSTing. This could happen if the motherboard isn't getting power. Recheck all your connections, especially the ones to the motherboard.

Comment: Using the Mobo's VGA port. I'll double check the connectors. I figured it was not POSTing.

Comment: Still nothing. Everything is plugged in tightly. Checked the power and everything looks to be showing it has power.

Comment: Try with minimal system configuration, i mean tear apart almost everything (_most  of RAMs, HDDs, ODDs, add-in GPUs/cards, ..._) and try again...

Comment: Bad PSU, improperly installed cable, something else knocked loose, left screwdriver in box and it's shorting something...

Comment: Can it be a bad PSU if I just bought it? Everything powers on and I used one of those mobile PSU testers and all the lights came on. ADDED the system and power supply being used.

Comment: You've never bought something that was defective out of the box before??

Comment: Does not happen that often. I've had it happen before but is it bad/broken/defective if stuff powers on just does not POST?

Comment: Could be.  Have you tried simply swapping in the old PSU?

Comment: I don't have the old PSU hence getting a new one.

Comment: So you don't know if the box ever worked in the first place?

Comment: Oh the box worked fine then I gave the power supply out and bought a new one.

Answer (score 0):

My bet would be on a DOA Power Supply.  Very common, contact the distributor and have them replace it.  If it does it again, then it's probably not the PSU.